# Bootstrap header doesn't collapse properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, header

I am developing a web-radio and stumbled upon some trouble with Bootstrap navbar-toggle button which should adaptively collapse header content.

At the page load the button works for the first few times. But then the vertical scrollbar appears on the side of my page, and as soon as it happens, button doesn't collapse header content anymore.

UPD: I found out that the cause of my problem is the list of 10 recently played tracks taken from Icecast's  *playlist.log*  **file and rendered by Tomcat server to special page**  *my.site/titles.jsp*  **and then with jQuery function** 
 $('#tracklist').html()  **being appended to the index page.**

This happens each time after page load with average latency of 2.5s due to response time from Last.fm API from where I get track covers for each element in the recent tracklist. So when I press the navbar-toggle button, the header uncollapses adding its height to the page body. The getTitles()  **function appends recent tracklist with 10 rows of text which is invisible by default. Despite being invisible this list increases the page body height too at the moment when it's appending to the page. And when it happens the header toggle button can't collapse header content anymore.**

I am using bootstrap version 3.3.7.

Here is the screenshot from my site:

[Scrollbar appeared and button doesn't work anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZFc2.jpg)

*My index.jsp page code:*

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}" />
    <!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}" />
    <title>Web&nbsp;radio&nbsp;&#9899;&nbsp;</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="skin/image/favicon.ico?" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skin/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar-wrapper navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".headerContent" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="logo navbar-brand" onclick="reload()">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse headerContent">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="toggles">
        <li class="active"><a tabindex="0" role="button" id="amp" onclick="_setMedia('amp')"><span>D&amp;B channel</span></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0" role="button" id="chl" onclick="_setMedia('chl')"><span>Chillout channel</span></a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="0" role="button" id="dsc" onclick="_setMedia('dsc')">                   <span>Disco channel</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${empty loggedInUser}">
          <div class="row navbar-right">
            <div class="auth navbar-text">
              <a tabindex="0" href="login" target="_blank"><span>Login</span> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="auth navbar-text"><a tabindex="0" href="register" target="_blank"><span>Register</span> </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
          <div class="row navbar-right">
            <div class="auth navbar-text"><a><span>Hello ${loggedInUser}! &nbsp;</span></a></div>
            <div class="auth navbar-text"><a tabindex="0" id="logout" href="logout">Logout</a></div>
           </div>
         </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div>
        <div class="container" id="canvas">
            <div class="row" id="stations">
                <div class="col-md-3" id="nowPlayingImg">
                    <!--* Now playing image taken from the Last.fm API *-->
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <div class="jp-jplayer" id="jquery_jplayer_1"></div>
                    <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio-stream" role="application" aria-label="media player">
                        <div class="jp-type-single">
                            <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">

                                <div class="subdiv">
                                    <div class="jp-controls">
                                        <a tabindex="0" role="button"><i class="fa fa-play jp-play fa-2x gradient-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="jp-details">
                                        <div class="jp-title">
                                            <p id="track-title">&nbsp;</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="jp-volume-controls">
                                    <a tabindex="0" role="button"><i class="fa fa-volume-off jp-mute gradient-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    <a tabindex="0" role="button"><i class="fa fa-volume-up jp-volume-max gradient-icon" tabindex="1" role="button" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                                        <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div tabindex="0" class="onclick-menu" id="recent">
                                    <i role="button" class="fa fa-bars gradient-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <!-- here the list of 10 recently played tracks is being appended -->
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="jp-no-solution">
                                <span>Update Required</span>
                                To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/player.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function reload() {
            window.location.reload(false);
        }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
::selection {
  background: var(--player-bg-color); 
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: var(--player-bg-color);
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: url('../image/bg.jpg') no-repeat !important;
  -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
}
a {
  outline: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
:root {
  --font-fam: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  --whitey-color: #fafafa;
  --header-row-h: 110px;
  --header-row-minh: 65px;
  --player-bg-color: #131415;
  --player-bg2-color: #202224;
  --row-background: rgb(24, 24, 24);
  --logo-img: url("../image/logo.png");
  --hover-text-color: #E0B35B;
}

.auth {
  line-height: 70px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left :0;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.auth a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
}

.auth a:hover,
.auth a:focus,
.auth a:active {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar {
  border: none !important;
}

.active > a {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.active > a > span {
  border-bottom: 3px solid black !important;
  border-top: 3px solid black !important;
}
.active > a:hover > span {
  border-bottom: 3px solid var(--hover-text-color) !important;
  border-top: 3px solid var(--hover-text-color) !important;
}

.container-fluid {
  background: #dea437 !important;
  /*background: linear-gradient(0, var(--hover-text-color), #dea437);*/
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

#toggles a {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  background: #dea437 !important;
  /*background: linear-gradient(0, var(--hover-text-color), #dea437);*/
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;;
  line-height: 80px;
}
#toggles a:hover {
  background: #000 !important;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: var(--hover-text-color);
}
#toggles a:hover span {
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
}
#toggles a span {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
}
.logo {
  background: var(--logo-img) no-repeat;
  background-size: var(--header-row-h);
  opacity: 1.0;
  height: var(--header-row-h);
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: var(--header-row-h);
  max-height: var(--header-row-h);
  min-height: var(--header-row-h);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.onclick-menu {
    width: 32px;


height: 32px;
  color: #171e2f;
  position: absolute; /*absolute;*/
  top: 50px;
  left: 450px;
  float:right;
  display: inline-block; /*block*/
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  outline: 0;
  transition: all 0.33s ease-in;
}

.onclick-menu-content {
    font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    pointer-events: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: -473px;
    width: 515px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 16px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin-top: 19px;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 5px;
}

.onclick-menu:focus {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.onclick-menu:focus .onclick-menu-content {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.onclick-menu-content li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #181818;

}
.onclick-menu-content li:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #222222;
}

.onclick-menu-content li {
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    display: block;
    height: 34px;
    z-index: -5;
    line-height: 34px;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: default;
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.onclick-menu-content li:hover {
    transform: translateX(3px);
}


.onclick-menu-content a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--whitey-color);
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 32px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.onclick-menu-content a:hover {
    color: var(--hover-text-color);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.onclick-menu-content li:hover > img {
    filter: none;
}

.onclick-menu-content li > img {
    padding-right: 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
    filter: grayScale(100%);
    vertical-align: middle;
}
  .onclick-menu-content ul:first-child {
    filter:none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var tit = '\xa0';
var jP = $("#jquery_jplayer_1");
var media = "http://my.icecast.stream:9000/live";
var cur = 'amp';
var space = String.fromCharCode(160);
var rec = String.fromCharCode(9899);
var refresh = '<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-fw gradient-icon"></i>';
var fa = $(".fa");

var url = 'http://my.icecast.stream:9000/json.xsl';

var _mountPoint, p_width, marquee_dur;
var p_marquee = $('.jp-title p');

_mountPoint = '/live';

//function for parsing titles and covers
function radioTitle() {

    if (cur !== null) {

        if (cur === 'amp') { //cur - current station
            $.ajax({  type: 'GET',
                url: url,
                async: true,
                jsonpCallback: 'parseMusic',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (json) {

                    tit = json[_mountPoint]['title'];
                    getTitles();
                    getCover(true);
                    document.title = "MyWeb Radio @" + space + tit.concat(space + rec + space);
                    $('#track-title').text(tit ? tit : space);
                    //setting up 'marquee' (title) speed:
                    setSpeed();

                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
                }
            });

        } else if (cur === 'chl' || cur === 'dsc') {
            var fm = "My Web-Radio @ Chillout FM / ";
            getCover(false);
            document.title = cur ==='chl' ? fm + "Chillout" + space + rec + space : fm + "Disco" + space + rec + space;
            // console.log(cur);
        }
    }
}

//setting trackname scroll speed
function setSpeed() {
    p_width = p_marquee.width();
    if (p_width > 350) {
        marquee_dur = 0.16 * (p_width / 7.7865) + 20;
        p_marquee.css('animation', 'marquee linear infinite');
        p_marquee.css('animation-duration', marquee_dur + 's');
    } else {
        p_marquee.css('animation', 'none');
        p_marquee.css('transform', 'translate(-50%,0)');
    }
}

//bars button icon
var bars = '<i class="fa fa-bars gradient-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>';

//getting cover image for current playing media from my.site/cover jsp page
function getCover(isMain) {
    if (isMain) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'cover',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#nowPlayingImg').html(response);
            }
        });
    } else {
        // $('#nowPlayingImg').html('<img width="110px" align="middle" src="../skin/image/music-elems.png" alt="cover">');

    }

}

//getting list of 10 recently played tracks from my.site/titles jsp page
function getTitles() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'titles',
        dataType: 'html',

        success: function (response) {
            $('#recent').html(bars + response);
        }
    });

}

$(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout(function () {radioTitle();}, 2000);
    setInterval(function () {radioTitle();}, 15000);

    //setting client's timezone cookie
    var dateVar = new Date();
    var timezone = dateVar.getTimezoneOffset()/60 * (-1);
    document.cookie="TZOffset=" + timezone + ";path=/";

    //init jPlayer
    jP.jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: media
            });
        },

        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1",
        supplied: "mp3",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        autoBlur: false,
        keyEnabled: true
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        var isPaused = jP.data().jPlayer.status.paused;

        if (isPaused) {
            jP.jPlayer("clearMedia");
            jP.jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3: media
            });
        }
    }, 9000);
});

//Toggle active tabs
$('#toggles').find('li').on('click', function() {
    $('#toggles').find('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

//Toggle play/pause icons
$(".subdiv .jp-controls a").click(function () {
    $(this).find(fa).toggleClass('fa-play fa-pause');

});

var lastAmp, lastChl, lastDsc, last;
var stream = $(".jp-audio-stream"), subDivs = $(".jp-details, .counter, .onclick-menu");

//Switching the stations
function _setMedia(str) {

    cur = str;

        switch (str) {
            case 'chl': {
                if (!lastChl) {
                    last = true;
                    $('#nowPlayingImg').html('<img width="110" align="middle" src="http://my.site/img/logo.png" alt="cover">');
                    lastChl = !lastChl;
                    lastDsc = false;
                    lastAmp = false;
                    media = "http://my.icecast.stream:9000/chillout";
                    jP.jPlayer("setMedia", {
                        mp3: media
                    });
                    stream.width(115);
                    subDivs.hide();
                    break;
                } else {
                    last = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            case 'dsc': {
                if (!lastDsc) {
                    last = true;
                    $('#nowPlayingImg').html('<img width="110" align="middle" src="my.site/img/logo.png" alt="cover">');
                    lastDsc = !lastDsc;
                    lastChl = false;
                    lastAmp = false;
                    media = "http://my.icecast.stream:9000/disco";
                    jP.jPlayer("setMedia", {
                        mp3: media
                    });
                    stream.width(115);
                    subDivs.hide();
                    break;
                } else {
                    last = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            case 'amp': {
                if (!lastAmp) {
                    last = true;
                    getCover(true);
                    lastAmp = !lastAmp;
                    lastChl = false;
                    lastDsc = false;
                    media = "http://my.icecast.stream:9000/live";
                    jP.jPlayer("setMedia", {
                        mp3: media
                    });
                    stream.width(473);
                    // document.querySelector('marquee').start();
                    subDivs.show();
                    break;
                } else {
                    last = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (last) {
            $(".jp-controls").find(fa).removeClass('fa-pause').addClass('fa-play');
        }

}
```